# Is time constant the same for linear system for all time?

Tags: temperature, time, measurements, laplace-transform

I have heard that if you take a measurement $T_1$ and wait, then take another measurement $T_2$ and then find $\Delta T = T_2 - T_1$. Then 63% of $\Delta T$ + $T_1$ will represent the measurement when we can find the time constant.

[image]

So I took a PT100 sensor and measure temperature raising from 16C to 98C.

[image]

The blue line is the perfect transfer function model:

$$G(s) = \frac{1}{900s + 1}$$

And the orange line is the temperature measurement.

**Question:**

Does the orange line have the same time constant if I pick out two measurement and find the time when $\Delta T$ is 63%?

Comment: It's not between any two arbitrary times on the curve, it's between any time and the stead-state value it is approaching.

Comment: @DKNguyen So the picture I show, is not correct?

Comment: It does not look like the orange will have the same time constant since it varies a bit from your ideal. Probably measurement error and other environmental factors like heat loss to ambient or something. Your curve looks a hell of a lot better than mine did though.

Comment: @DKNguyen This is water temperature. I want to measure if the temperature have almost the same time constant for 30 to 100

Comment: I think there are confounding factors such as losing more heat to ambient as things get hotter, how well you stir it, measurement error, and evaporation if you have any. I found it really tough to control things when I was trying to make a water calorimeter. Unless your vessel is vacuum insulated and stirred, you're going to have noticeable deviations. Even the energy added from stirring will increase the temperature.

Comment: @DKNguyen Here I have the measurements. https://gist.github.com/DanielMartensson/0c21ff5a3abb912a2119f03dc078d487

Comment: @DKNguyen So I always need to measure from steady state temperature? E.g room temperature to 100?

Comment: @DKNguyen Do you have the transfer function formula for water temperature and volume?

Comment: @DKNguyen In this case, its 10 liters of water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the time-constant stays the same for all time.
And there is a $63\%$-rule valid for all the time.
But as @DKNguyen already said in the first comment, you got it slightly wrong.
The correct rule, valid for all $t$, is
$$\frac{T(t+\tau)-T(t)}{T(\infty)-T(t)}=0.63$$

[image]

To understand where this rule comes from, we need to go back
to the differential equation
$$\frac{dT(t)}{dt}=\frac{1}{\tau}(T(\infty)-T(t))$$
where $T(t)$ is the temperature measured at time $t$,
$T(\infty)$ is the temperature measured after waiting an infinite time,
and $\tau$ is the time constant.

This, with the starting condition $T(0)$, has the solution
$$T(t)=T(\infty)+(T(0)-T(\infty))e^{-t/\tau}$$

From this solution, with a little bit of algebra, you can derive
$$\frac{T(t+\tau)-T(t)}{T(\infty)-T(t)}=1-e^{-1}$$
which is just the $63\%$-rule given above.

Comment: So in practice, I can take first measurement at any time, then wait for the steady state and then compute the difference between time and steady state and then find the time constant?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson In theory, measuring $T$ at two times and at $\infty$ would be enough. But in practice it is always better to do measurements on more time points, and thus reduce the statistical error.

Comment: If I want to compute the time constant? I know it's water and I know the volume. What's the theoretical model then of first order system? $G(s) = \frac{1}{Ts + 1}$

Comment: I can give you measurements of 20 liters water from 22C to 98C later. Then we can compare the theoretical model with the real measurements? Give me 2 hours.

Answer (score 2):

If the rate of temperature change is proportional to the difference between the current temperature and the eventual temperature,

$$
\frac d{dt} T = k( T_\text{eq} - T),
\tag1
$$

then the temperature will exponentially approach the equilibrium value,

$$
T(t) = T_\text{eq} + (T_\text{start}-T_\text{eq}) e^{-kt}
\tag2
$$

with time constant $\tau=1/k$.

You're correct that this time constant should be the same along the entire curve.

This model is usually a good first approximation for temperature evolution for a system in a constant-temperature heat bath, because generally the heat flow across a boundary is proportional to the temperature difference, and generally the temperature of a system is proportional to the heat content. However this second assumption breaks down in materials undergoing a phase change, where energy added to the system goes into changing its state rather than changing its temperature.

Here in the twenty-first century we can do better fitting than just choosing two magic points along the curve.  Think of deviations from the exponential approach (2) as giving you information about the accuracy of the model (1). Your data are very pretty, and follow the exponential curve very nicely on average, but have some non-exponential structure that may or may not be physically interesting --- you haven't said enough about your setup for us to be able to tell.